# Moving Item UnauthorizedAccessException,why is access to destination denied?

Tags: windows, powershell

I tried to move one file

```
PS C:\Users\romanrublev\Downloads> move-Item  -path ${C:\Users\romanrublev\Downloads$Query 243.xlsx} -destination ${C:\Users\romanrublev\Videos}
Access to the path 'C:\Users\romanrublev\Videos' is denied.
At line:1 char:1
+ move-Item  -path ${C:\Users\romanrublev\Downloads$Query 243.xlsx} -d ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Users\romanrublev\Videos:String) [], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetContentReaderUnauthorizedAccessError
```

I am runing it from PowerShell as Administrator.
How to check file permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because 'Move-Item' expects to receive the destination path for the file and not just the folder.

**When you are saying:**

```
Move-Item -Path "C:\Users\romanrublev\Downloads$Query 243.xlsx" -Destination "C:\Users\romanrublev\Videos"
```

Move-Item thinks that you want to move file "$Query 243.xlsx" to "C:\Users\romanrublev" with the name 'Videos'. But the Videos already exist, and it is a system folder that is used by the user account.

**The correct way is:**

```
Move-Item -Path "C:\Users\romanrublev\Downloads$Query 243.xlsx" -Destination "C:\Users\romanrublev\Videos$Query 243.xlsx"
```